# Swift 2.1 - Array empty when searching - unsafe unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, option-type

My app terminates every time a value is entered/edited in the text fields for "notes", "task name" and "task length" values. If data for just one of them is entered/edited, the app crashes. The same line of code is highlighted as the cause of the error each time.

The problem is that the array I'm using is empty when I'm trying to search for a value. It should't be empty, but I don't know how to correct this. Could you please tell me a method to resolve this unsafe unwrapping in the code?

I'm using a split Master-Detail view controller. Attached is all the relevant code, from the 3 different View Controllers I'm using. The function in the Task VC is connected to the function in the Master VC - adds new data for a new task.

I've tried using do/try/catch, using the ! on the optional and using IF statements, but nothing I try seems to work. Please help me

Error + line of code highlighted in debugger:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

textFields[0].text = detail.valueForKey("moduleName") as? String
```

Detail View Controller

```
var tasks = [NSSet]() 

var courseWork: CourseWork? {
didSet {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.configureView()
    }

func configureView() { // Update the user interface for the detail view

if let detail = self.courseWork { 

    self.title = detail.valueForKey("courseWorkName")!.description 

    textFields[0].text = detail.valueForKey("moduleName") as? String //Error with this line
    textFields[1].text = detail.valueForKey("markAwarded") as? String 


func setupUIElements() {

//text fields
for textF in textFields {
    textF.delegate = self
}
textView.delegate = self

}

@IBOutlet var textFields: [UITextField]!

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    for (index, tf) in textFields.enumerate() {
        if textField == tf {
            saveTHeCourseWork(index == 0 ? "moduleName" : "markAwarded", value: textFields[index].text!)
        }
    }
    return true
}

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" { 

        saveTHeCourseWork("notes", value: textView.text) 

        textView.resignFirstResponder() 
    }
    return true
}
```

Task VC:

```
@IBOutlet weak var taskName: UITextField! 
@IBOutlet weak var taskLength: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var taskNotes: UITextView!

@IBAction func saveTask(sender: UIButton) { // function saves and updates data inputted into Task


        if task == nil { // task is blank, create new one
            MasterViewController().insertNewTask(taskName.text!, length: taskLength.text, startDate: startDate.date, dueDate: dueDate.date, notes: taskNotes.text, course: courseWork!) 

        } else {
            MasterViewController().updateTaskValues(taskName.text!, length: taskLength.text, startDate: startDate.date, dueDate: dueDate.date, notes: taskNotes.text, task: task!) // sends to Master Detail View Controller

            print ("Update task")
        }
```

Master VC:

```
func insertNewTask(name: String, length: String?, notes: String, course: CourseWork) {
    if let context = course.managedObjectContext {
        let task = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Task", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        let newTask = NSManagedObject(entity: task!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        newTask.setValue(name, forKey: "taskName") 
        newTask.setValue(notes, forKey: "notes")
        course.mutableSetValueForKey("tasks").addObject(newTask)
        // Save data to Object
        do {
            try course.managedObjectContext?.save()

        } catch {
            abort()
        }
```

Comment: Is `textFields` nil?

Comment: Please see if you can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu

Comment: Tried looking at dealing with Optionals, but I don't know how to apply it to my code. I'm just starting out at Swift unfortunately and I've tried everything I know

Comment: The answer I linked has had several contributors; we're trying to make it a comprehensive guide to understanding optionals & "unexpectedly found nil" errors. If a careful read of that page doesn't answer your question, please update this question to include what you've tried/checked already, rather than just "it's crashing; I don't know why".

Comment: I've included what I've attempted in the question, as you suggested.

Comment: I'm still having trouble seeing a reason not to mark this as a duplicate of the question I linked to. Not trying to be difficult, just trying to avoid duplicate content on SO. I'll  the dupehammer and let others chime in.

Comment: It just seems like you haven't connected `textfields` to anything in the XIB...